# Pre-WW2 location of Skalat

Tags: world-war-two, maps

Was Skalat on the border between Poland and USSR before WW2?  Is there a pre-WW2 map with Skalat? I am trying to confirm information from a 90-year old who reportedly crossed the former border between Poland and USSR during WW2 (July, 1941) at Skalat.

Comment: I would upvote this question if it included references/links to existing maps that would help me to understand the question.

Comment: This is a geography question, not a history question. ... and a trivial geography question at that, double whammy.

Comment: @TylerDurden If you look at the map at [wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skalat) Skalat is in Ukraine. It changed the last centuries between Poland, Austria, Russia, again Austria and Poland, then USSR (Ukraine) and since 1991 Ukraine. The question could be better, but in my opinion it is not the question where Skalat is located, but how the borders changed around Skalat - so for me it is historical.

Answer (score 1):

You could check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skalat)

> In the immediate post-World War One period, Skalat was seized by local Ukrainian activists, who declared that **the town was part of West Ukrainian People's Republic**. Polish - Ukrainian tension escalated, and climaxed in the Polish–Ukrainian War. On April 23, 1919, Ukrainian activists murdered a popular Roman Catholic parish priest from Skalat, Rev. Walerian Raba, and on July 16, 1919, the town **was captured by the Polish Army**.
>
> In 1923 Skalat became the seat of a county in the Tarnopol Voivodeship.

[Tarnopol Voivodeship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarnopol_Voivodeship) was an administrative region of interwar Poland (1918–1939)

There is also a [Map in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tarnopolskie1939.jpg) where you can see, that Skalat is near the border to USSR (Ucraine).

[image]

---

[Another source](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0018_0_18682.html), outside Wikipedia:

> SKALAT (Pol. Skałat), town in *Tarnopol district, Ukraine. Formerly within Poland[...]reverting to Poland between the two world wars.[...]As a result of Skalat's proximity to the Russian border,[...]
>
> When the town passed to Soviet rule (1939–41),[...]

You see, the town is near the border and changed the ruler.